# Changing the close reason of a question

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, vote-to-close

The question [How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24552/15334) was originally written [in a rather confusing way](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/24552/1), to the point where I considered it warranted to vote for closure until the question is clarified.  [Peter Cordes’s edit](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/24552/2) improved it to the point where I thought that reason for closure no longer applied (and the asker seems to agree witht the edit), but even then I think the question is, if not an exact duplicate of, then at least sufficiently overlapping the subject of an older question,  [BIOS interrupts vs Hardware interrupts](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16521/15334), that it is probably close-worthy for that reason.

However, as I have already voted to close the question once, I am barred from voting to close it again.  I did mention my preferred duplicate target in the comments, but I am afraid it was buried unnoticed in the heated discussion about something else.

Is there a way around this?  If nothing else, anyone who agrees this is a duplicate should feel free to vote accordingly, or otherwise, explain here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way around this, unfortunately. If you have participated in the successful closure of a question, you can't close vote it again. And the system doesn't let you flag either, because close flags and close votes are (internally) identical.

Your best bet is to hope that your comment gets upvoted enough that it's visible in the Close Votes queue, or that somebody else does a duplicate vote with that question as the target.